# Best Practice of Error and Exception handling for a C# API

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a simple and small API which fires out a bunch of Web-requests and works with the responses. The user only calls the method and provides a callback where he can work with the data, something like the following:

```
var someData = new SomeData();
API.GetSomeDataFromTheWeb((d)=>{someData = d;});
```

For each response I implemented a concrete class holding the data. In addition I want the user to handle any occurring error and exception by himself. This could be a WebException, JsonSerializationException or any custom error which can occur. 
How do I pass those different exception and errors to the user who then can retrieve the needed information out of it to handle those exceptions and errors?

Comment: You just throw the exception. As long as it's documented that your method throws so and so exception for this and that condition, it's the coder's responsibility to handle that. You can use the built in exception classes or [design your own](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229064(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: or you could have a second action that will be called when an exception occurs.

Comment: Either let the exception be thrown, or catch it and wrap it in a custom exception which provides more information and throw that.

Comment: If you rethrow the exception be aware of how you impact included stack information on the rethrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Library (or API) development has to deal with exception handling slightly differently from how its handled in application development -

1. As you already wrote in your question, you would like the user to make the decision. This important, since a library can be used in multiple scenarios & its not possible to anticipate every situation where the library will be used and to have a policy in place. It should be the job of application, which knows the context & can have a policy for it.
2. Verify the arguments passed to your APIs (by the application). Throw an exception if they are incorrect.
3. State - Rolling back a partially completed operation

   Usually a single API's will call several APIs to perform the operation. Let's say some of the functions calls completed successfully and some did not.

   In such a case it will be desirable to roll back to an initial state and inform the caller about the error.

   Example

   ```
   try
   {
       // Database operations starts 
       // perform database operations
       transaction.Commit();
   }
   catch // anything goes wrong
   {
       // rollback
       transaction.RollBack();

       // Rethowing the *Same* exception
       throw;
   }
   ```
4. Hiding Implementation details from outside world & keeping it secure.
   This has to be used with care, but I'll convey my opinion about it.

In the over example, probably the stack trace may expose too much information about my implementation & database that it could compromise on security.

In such a case, it might be useful to catch one type of  & throw another new exception.

```
try
{
    // Database operations starts 
    // perform database operations
    transaction.Commit();
}
catch (DataException ex)
{
    // rollback
    transaction.RollBack();

    // I'm keeping the original error but lying about the stack stace
    throw new InvalidOperationException(name, ex);
}
```

Now, let me talk about raising exceptions .

Throw an exception when the API cant perform its task completely. A few points to bear in mind:

1. Choose a type (Exception-derived type) that is most meaningful. This will give a chance for the code up in the call stack to appropriately handle the specific case.

   In case there is no .Net exception that matches exact semantics, create a custom one.
2. Incase you create a hierarchy of Custom exceptions. It's best to keep the hierarchy shallow. So as to create few base classes, because base classes act as a way of treating all errors as one error. On the same lines, never throw `System.Exception`
3. Do keep the message of the exception detailed enough for the developer to fix, in case the exception goes unhandled. At the same time, too much information to outside world can be a security issue.

**Edit 1 :**

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Reads an Employee by its ID
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="ID">Unique identifier</param>
  /// <param name="dbContext">Contains inforamtion about how to connect to database</param>
  /// <returns>Employee linked to ID; Null if no record is linked</returns>  
  public Employee ReadEmployee(string ID, IDataBaseContext dbContext)
  {
       if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ID))
           throw new ArgumentException("Unique id must be supplied to read the record");

       // Validate if the database can be accessed using db Context, if not throw another exception. 
       // Because it's preventing the API from doing its job

       // read and return the record
    }
```

I'll raise an error only if I cannot perform the reading operation. If a null is returned after reading the data, it's okay, the API has done its job.

What to do with null value, is something I'll let the caller decide.

Perhaps in a search dialog it will be fine to show an empty result when null is returned.

But it could an exception in another business case.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. So you would always use exceptions for error handling? Even when the user is trying to retrieve data by ID and the ID does not exist (but would be valid) you would throw a custom exception?
That would mean that the user has to wrap every API call in a try catch block right? Isn't that a usability concern?

Comment: I’m glad you found the information useful.  
About your question … Yes, incase my API (or utility method) **cannot** perform its task, I always let the caller know that there has been something wrong - by raising exceptions & never swallowing the ones raised by functions within API (I don’t use special return values). 
I support state integrity, and incase the state has been corrupted beyond repair, its perhaps best to inform the user to terminate the state, rather than keeping the application running with a corrupted state which can rampant misbahviours & curropted stated across the system

Comment: About not finding a record when an ID was supplied, no I will not raise an exception because the API did what its job was, to read the record.  I’ll raise an error only if I cannot perform the reading operation. I’ll explain it with an example & edit my answer.

Comment: About d last question, wrap every API call & usability concern – I’ll convey my thought process. 
We all churn out huge code using .NET’s Library functions, almost every .net function can produce exception(s), but we use try catch block discreetly.
When we write an API (or a utility function), in principal for user its similar to a Framework Class Library function, so why have a different exception handling scheme there.
So I don’t think we need a try catch on every API call, it should be just when needed.
But please write me a comment if you think otherwise and we can discuss it further

Answer (score 0):

Use `throw WebException("your message")` like this. Use any exception you want. User will have to catch it and get your message using `ex.Message` property (where `ex` is the exception name)